# $\frac {1} {ab} + \frac {1} {ac} + \frac {1} {ad} + \frac {1} {bc} + \frac {1} {bd} + \frac {1} {cd}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

I found this questions from past year maths competition in my country, I've tried any possible way to find it, but it is just way too hard.

3. given $$ \frac {1} {a} + \frac {1} {b} + \frac {1} {c} + \frac {1} {d} = 65, \frac {1} {a^2} + \frac {1} {b^2} + \frac {1} {c^2} + \frac {1} {d^2} = 209$$
   find $$\frac {1} {ab} + \frac {1} {ac} + \frac {1} {ad} + \frac {1} {bc} + \frac {1} {bd} + \frac {1} {cd}$$

(A) $2006$ (B) $2007$ (C) $2008$ (D) $2009$ (E) $2010$

I've use the direct way (make them become 1 fraction)
$$\frac {abc+abd+acd+bcd} {abcd} = 65$$
$$\frac {a^2b^2c^2+a^2b^2d^2+a^2c^2d^2+b^2c^2d^2} {a^2b^2c^2d^2} = 209$$
$$\frac {a^2b^2c^2d^2(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd)} {a^3b^3c^3d^3}$$
$$\frac {(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd)} {abcd}$$

but it doesn't make sense with these power $abcd$ thing

Comment: Looks like "the pass year maths competition in your country" is the square festival.

Comment: The answers to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373283/x2-frac-x2x-12-2010#1373284) previous question of yours contain very clear hints. The "principle" by which to solve the problem is very much the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}\right)^2=\\\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{d}\right)^2+2\left(\frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{ac}+\frac{1}{ad}+\frac{1}{bc}+\frac{1}{bd}+\frac{1}{cd}\right)\\65^2=209+2\left(\frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{ac}+\frac{1}{ad}+\frac{1}{bc}+\frac{1}{bd}+\frac{1}{cd}\right)\\\left(\frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{ac}+\frac{1}{ad}+\frac{1}{bc}+\frac{1}{bd}+\frac{1}{cd}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(65^2-209\right)=2008$$

Answer (score 10):

**Hint:** Try expanding $\left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} + \frac{1}{d}\right)^2$.

Answer (score 3):

$(1/a+1/b+1/c+1/d)^2=\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}+\frac{1}{d^2}+2\times \frac{1}{a}\times\frac{1}{b}+2\times\frac{1}{a}\times\frac{1}{c}+2\times\frac{1}{a}\times\frac{1}{d}+2\times\frac{1}{b}\times\frac{1}{c}+2\times\frac{1}{b}\times\frac{1}{d}+2\times\frac{1}{c}\times\frac{1}{d}$

$(65)^2=209+2(\frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{ac}+\frac{1}{ad}+\frac{1}{bc}+\frac{1}{bd}+\frac{1}{cd})$

$4225-209=2(\frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{ac}+\frac{1}{ad}+\frac{1}{bc}+\frac{1}{bd}+\frac{1}{cd})$

$(\frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{ac}+\frac{1}{ad}+\frac{1}{bc}+\frac{1}{bd}+\frac{1}{cd})=2008$

Answer (score 3):

More, clearly we have $$\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}\right)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}\right)=65\times 65$$ $$\implies \left(\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{ac}+\frac{1}{ad}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{bc}+\frac{1}{bd}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{ac}+\frac{1}{bc}+\frac{1}{c^2}+\frac{1}{cd}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{ad}+\frac{1}{bd}+\frac{1}{cd}+\frac{1}{d^2}\right)=4225$$ $$\implies \left(\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}+\frac{1}{d^2}\right)+2\left(\frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{ac}+\frac{1}{ad}+\frac{1}{bc}+\frac{1}{bd}+\frac{1}{cd}\right)=4225$$ Now, setting the corresponding values, we have  $$ \left(209\right)+2\left(\frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{ac}+\frac{1}{ad}+\frac{1}{bc}+\frac{1}{bd}+\frac{1}{cd}\right)=4225$$ $$ \implies \frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{ac}+\frac{1}{ad}+\frac{1}{bc}+\frac{1}{bd}+\frac{1}{cd}=\frac{4225-209}{2}=2008$$